# Warning: Undefined variable en php chart.js

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, chart.js

Tengo el siguiente codigo para graficar registros de entrega de materiales en mi negocio

Compradores.php

Con este codigo creo traigo la informacion de mi base de datos

```
<?php

$item = null;
$valor = null;

$ventas = ControladorVentas::ctrMostrarVentas($item, $valor);
$clientes = ControladorClientes::ctrMostrarClientes($item, $valor);

$arrayClientes = array();
$arraylistaClientes = array();

foreach ($ventas as $key => $valueVentas) {
  
  foreach ($clientes as $key => $valueClientes) {
    
      if($valueClientes["id"] == $valueVentas["id_cliente"]){

        #Capturamos los Clientes en un array
        array_push($arrayClientes, $valueClientes["identificador"]);

        #Capturamos las nombres y los valores netos en un mismo array
        $arraylistaClientes = array($valueClientes["identificador"] => $valueVentas["total"]);

        #Sumamos los netos de cada cliente
        foreach ($arraylistaClientes as $key => $value) {
          
          $sumaTotalClientes[$key] += $value;
        
        }

      }   
  }

}

#Evitamos repetir nombre
$noRepetirNombres = array_unique($arrayClientes);

?>

<!--=====================================
VENDEDORES
======================================-->

<div class="box box-primary">
    
    <div class="box-header with-border">
    
        <h3 class="box-title">Supervisores</h3>
  
    </div>

    <div class="box-body">
        
        <div class="chart-responsive">
            
            <div class="chart" id="bar-chart2" style="height: 355px;"></div>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>

<script>
    
//BAR CHART
var bar = new Morris.Bar({
  element: 'bar-chart2',
  resize: true,
  data: [
     <?php
    
    foreach($noRepetirNombres as $value){

      echo "{y: '".$value."', a: '".$sumaTotalClientes[$value]."'},";

    }

  ?>
  ],
  barColors: ['#4ddc95'],
  xkey: 'y',
  ykeys: ['a'],
  labels: ['Entregas'],
  preUnits: '$',
  hideHover: 'auto'
});


</script>
```

Y con el siguiente los posiciono en la vista

Reportes.php

```
<?php

if($_SESSION["perfil"] == "Especial"){

  echo '<script>

    window.location = "inicio";

  </script>';

  return;

}

?>
<div class="content-wrapper">

  <section class="content-header">
    
    <h1>
      
      Reportes de entregas
    
    </h1>

    <ol class="breadcrumb">
      
      <li><a href="inicio"><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> Inicio</a></li>
      
      <li class="active">Reportes de entregas</li>
    
    </ol>

  </section>

  <section class="content">

    <div class="box">

    <div class="box-body">
        
        <div class="row">

        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <?php


            ?>

           </div>
          
        </div>

      </div>

      <div class="box-header with-border">

        <div class="input-group">

          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="daterange-btn2">
           
            <span>
              <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> 

              <?php

                if(isset($_GET["fechaInicial"])){

                  echo $_GET["fechaInicial"]." - ".$_GET["fechaFinal"];
                
                }else{
                 
                  echo 'Rango de fecha';

                }

              ?>
            </span>

            <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>

          </button>

        </div>

        <div class="box-tools pull-right">

        <?php

        if(isset($_GET["fechaInicial"])){

          echo '<a href="vistas/modulos/descargar-reporte.php?reporte=reporte&fechaInicial='.$_GET["fechaInicial"].'&fechaFinal='.$_GET["fechaFinal"].'">';

        }else{

           echo '<a href="vistas/modulos/descargar-reporte.php?reporte=reporte">';

        }         

        ?>
           
           <button class="btn btn-success" style="margin-top:5px">Descargar reporte en Excel</button>

          </a>

        </div>
         
      </div>

      <div class="box-body">
        
        <div class="row">

          <div class="col-xs-12">
            
            <?php

            include "reportes/grafico-ventas.php";

            ?>

          </div>

          <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
             
           <?php
           
           include "reportes/productos-mas-vendidos.php";
           
           ?>

           </div>

           <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
             
           <?php
           
           include "reportes/compradores.php";
           
           ?>

           </div>

          
          
        </div>

      </div>
      
    </div>

  </section>
 
 </div>
```

El resultado es el siguiente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi error me lo muestra en el momento en que intento reposicionar las graficas de la siguiente manera

```
 <div class="box-body">
        
        <div class="row">

          <div class="col-xs-12">
            
            <?php

            include "reportes/compradores.php";

            ?>

          </div>

          <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
             
           <?php
           
           include "reportes/productos-mas-vendidos.php";
           
           ?>

           </div>

           <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
             
           <?php
           
           include "reportes/grafico-ventas.php";
           
           ?>

           </div>
          
        </div>

      </div>
```

En el momento en que cambio las graficas supervisores y graficos de ventas de posicion me muestra el siguiente error en la grafica supervisores

`Warning: Undefined variable`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya declare la variable `$sumaTotalClientes` y solo borra el error de esta variable pero los nombres continuan ya revise mi archivo `compradores.php` y no encuentro cual sea el error ya que este solo lo muestra cuando lo cambio a la posicion principal y arriba mientras la deje abajo compartiendo espacio no.

Me podrian ayudar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

esos son warnigs, no errores, solo coloca al principio de tu codigo

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ERROR);
```

No es una solución definitiva pero te salva el dia, asi es php.
si deseas que no se muestren y hacerlo bien solo debes declarar las variables al inicio del codigo

Comment: Gracias si me sirvio